# When will Roo support the Spring Framework Version 4

Tags: spring-roo

Right now there are a lot of tools and projects that work with the new Spring 4 Framework and it is not possible to use Roo in those instances.  Also, there is a fix that affects the Roo gwt plugin that requires a new version of Roo (1.6).

When do you think we could see Roo 1.6 and a version of Roo that supports the Spring 4 Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think than the 1.2.6 version will be ready in short time (but I can't say how long). But I almost sure that 1.X branch will still using the Spring 3.x version. Could be a good improvement for v2.0.

Any way, You can vote the [Jira task](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3497) about it.

Comment: Roo 1.6? The current compiled version available at http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/ is 1.2.5. Are they planning to bypass 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5? Or is Roo Github only now?